# Animated examples of different interpolations formulas: any link?

Tags: mathematics, physics, simulations

I remember having spotted a link to a huge page with different equations to non linear interpolation curves, for example if you want to stop a car smoothly, etc.

Those can sometime be useful to emulate some real-world acceleration/velocity behaviors without the help of a physics engine, which can really simplify the code.

Any idea where this page is ? I can't manage to give google the right keywords...

EDIT:
I just searched on my previous laptop bookmarks, and I found it: http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/

Comment: and sorry if the question gets closed, but I'll put the link in the wiki, that's like the #1 thing I think is important to progammers when thinking about maths.

Comment: Since that link is actually an answer to your question, you should post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it mate.
http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/

Answer (score 10):

If you had searched for "easing formulas" it would've been the first result.

http://www.gizma.com/easing/

Comment: While this is useful, I think jokoon was looking for a specific page, and I do not think that this is the page he was looking for.

Comment: It's not that one but it has the equations, so that's good :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be the one:
http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/misc/transitions.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a realtime WYSIWYG interpolation editor: http://inloop.github.io/interpolator/