# Anybody remember this webpage?

Tags: mathematics, physics, animation

I remember visiting a webpage some time ago (1 year ago maybe)

It contained many java applets, describing how certain mathematical functions like sin, cos, arcsin, exp would make an object move, with an example of  animated ball next to it, with its curve and the function name.

It was quite exhaustive, and was quite handy to simulate physical behaviors, like bouncing ball, smoothing cameras...

I can't find it on google, Anybody remembering this page ?

Comment: Man that describes like 95% of the webpages on the internet created between 1997 and 2003.  Any other hints?  What color it was, maybe?

Comment: You should instead modify this question to ask about examples for the particular things you want to do.

Comment: I edited my question, what don't you understand ?

Comment: It's not that I don't understand. I didn't down vote you, but I knew you would get down voted. This question is more like the type of question you'd ask on a forum, not here. Here you'd ask for examples of what you want to do.

Comment: I think that [takes the guessing game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) to a complete new level.

Comment: "Fun" fact: you already asked this one year before. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11287/animated-examples-of-different-interpolations-formulas-any-link

Comment: haha yeah so it seems :) problem is, I can't really remember the right keyword to give google so I can find this back. Maybe this way I will have 2 times more chance to find it in my question history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://sol.gfxile.net/interpolation/

(sorry I forgot it was about interpolation)

Comment: Nice, that looks like a useful website. Remember to accept your answer.

Comment: can't do it until the day after tomorrow

Comment: @jokoon Remember to accept your answer.

Comment: done, appreciate the reminder :)